# php check if user is logged into another domain

Tags: php, cross-domain

Good evening everyone.

I am building a web platform where I need to know From (domain**2**.com) domain name 
whether the user is logged in into cms.domain**1**.com

Domain1 is a content management system
while Domain2 is an active website build in a cms.

So, I need to know whether the user is logged in into the cms, so I can give him an inline editor in his website.

Thanks.

Comment: You will just have to make up some service so that the server on domain*2*.com can as cms.domain*1*.com if the user is logged in.

Comment: well. by creating a service on the cms side, I ll have to implement it on the website side as well...